# Download files before build in gatsby wordpress

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

I have a client that im working with who needs his pdfs to be readable in browser and the user doesn't need to download them first and it turned out to not be an option to do it through Wordpress so I thought I can download them in gatsby before build everytime if they don't already exist and I was wondering if this is possible.

I found this repo: https://github.com/jamstack-cms/jamstack-ecommerce

that shows a way to do it with this code:

```
function getImageKey(url) {
  const split = url.split('/')
  const key = split[split.length - 1]
  const keyItems = key.split('?')
  const imageKey = keyItems[0]
  return imageKey
}

function getPathName(url, pathName = 'downloads') {
  let reqPath = path.join(__dirname, '..')
  let key = getImageKey(url)
  key = key.replace(/%/g, "")
  const rawPath = `${reqPath}/public/${pathName}/${key}`
  return rawPath
}

async function downloadImage (url) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const path = getPathName(url)
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path)
    const response = await axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream'
    })
    response.data.pipe(writer)
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
  })
}
```

but It doesn't seem to work if i put it in my createPages and i cant use it outside it either because i don't have access to graphql to query the data first.

any idea how to do this?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: when i put the code inside createPages the queries does not run and gives me Cannot query field "allWordpressWpTechnicalInfo" on type "Query". for example.

Comment: Have you tried looking at some of the [other APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onPreBuild) for gatsby node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress source example is defined as `async`:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
```

... so you can already use `await` to download your file(-s) just after querying data (and before `createQuery()` call). It should (NOT TESTED) be as easy as:

```
// Check for any errors
if (result.errors) {
  console.error(result.errors)
}

// Access query results via object destructuring
const { allWordpressPage, allWordpressPost } = result.data

const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/page.js`)
allWordpressPage.edges.forEach(edge => {

  // for one file per edge
  // url taken/constructed from some edge property
  await downloadImage (url);

  createPage({
```

Of course for multiple files you should use `Promise.all` to wait for [resolving] all [returned promise] downloads before creating page:

```
allWordpressPage.edges.forEach(edge => {

  // for multiple files per edge(page)
  // url taken/constructed from some edge properties in a loop

  // adapth 'paths' of iterable (edge.xxx.yyy...)
  // and/or downloadImage(image) argument, f.e. 'image.someUrl'
  await Promise.all( 
    edge.node.someImageArrayNode.map( image => { return downloadImage(image); }
  );

  createPage({
```

If you need to pass/update image nodes (for components usage)  you should be able to mutate nodes, f.e.:

```
  await Promise.all( 
    edge.node.someImageArrayNode.map( image => { 
      image["fullUrl"] = `/publicPath/${image.url}`;
      return downloadImage(image.url); // return Promise at the end
    }
  );

  createPage({
    path: slugify(item.name),
    component: ItemView,
    context: {
      content: item,
      title: item.name,
      firstImageUrl: edge.node.someImageArrayNode[0].fullUrl,
      images: edge.node.someImageArrayNode
```